# Mercurial - how to fetch latest changes from parent of fork?

Tags: mercurial, fork, bitbucket

I've been dabbling with Mercurial for a short while now, and I've now set up several projects on BitBucket, one forking off of the other.

I've been able to make changes to each repo with no problem, but one thing I can't figure out, is how to keep the fork up-to-date with changes from the parent repo?

After I've forked a repo, I only see the commits from that repo up to X revision, after which point I only see the fork's own commits, no new parent commits.

I'm pretty certain that during my dabbling with git, I was able to rebase to the latest parent revision, but that was awhile back and I'd rather not guess my way into bad habits :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just perform the `pull` with the source repository as an argument. It will pull all the changes done after your previous pull (or from the time you forked the project, if no pulls were performed).

After that you will have some additional heads, which you have to merge with your ones.

Answer (score 11):

Here are 3 essential steps:

```
hg pull -u path_to_parent
hg merge
hg commit -m"updates from parent"
```

Or you could install [fetch](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FetchExtension) extension that combines all these steps:

```
hg fetch path_to_parent
```